# How to make world canvas ui image to equal size in orthographic camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 2018 and my game 2d but i use 3d (Orthographic Camera).
How to make below links coin effect?

https://youtu.be/hiRdux33UCs?t=18

I tried with above guide. I made world space canvas and create ui image object under the canvas for coin image. But my project was orthographic project and i made zoom in and zoom out features by set size of camera's orthographic size. So the world space canvasses(coin pregfabs) can getting bigger or smaller when i zoom in or out. I want the coin (world canvas > ui image) has equal size even if i resize the orthographic camera.
Is there have any good ideas?

Comment: If you want a canvas to match your camera, it shouldn't be a world space canvas.  You should change its _Render Mode_ to _Screen Space - Overlay_.

Comment: @Foggzie Oh you mean that i must make particle (canvas > ui image) with screen space and set position with screen space (rect transform <-> world space)?